# Mouse events inside a restricted container in javascript

Tags: javascript, containers, mouseevent

```js
var contain = document.getElementById("contain");
var newBlock = document.createElement("div");
var moveIt = function(event) {
  //document.body.appendChild(newBlock);
  contain.appendChild(newBlock); //comment this out, and apply previous line
  newBlock.className = "block";
    var posX = event.clientX - 50;
  var posY = event.clientY - 50;
  newBlock.style.top = posY + "px";
  newBlock.style.left = posX + "px";
  newBlock.innerHTML = "posX = " + (posX + 50) + "<br />posY = " + (posY + 50);
}

var letsDoIt = contain.addEventListener("mousemove", moveIt);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#contain {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="contain">
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm just starting in javascript. I didn't get to jquery yet, so I would be grateful for pure JS answer (if possible).

I want to create a div "inside" another div area via different mouse events, but I have following problem.

If new div (block) is a child of the container div, then whenever I press block, it will change position, even when this position is outside container. When use event "mousemove", it will move block everywhere.

If block is child of body, then new block will be created when pressed inside container but outside of the block.

Here's fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flagoon/av9zup1y/3/)

Comment: Hi, when using SO try and use Snippets instead of jsFiddle.  I've updated your post to a snippet..  Nice thing about snippets is SO users can just click the Run Code Snippet, and not have to go to an external site.

Comment: I checked your demo but I don't understand exactly what are you trying to achieve. Do you need the inner div not to cross the borders of the parent div (only stay inside the boundaries of the parent div?) Could you elaborate ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem, but heres a piece of information you may not know: if you add "pointer-events: none;" CSS to ".block", the mouse events will be triggered on the element underneath (parent), and never on the block itself.

Comment: @DejanBogatinovski this is exactly what I wanted to do. Workaholic's answer was what I needed. Didn't know about pointer-events property. It's my first day here. How can I upvote posts or make one as answer?

Comment: @ZenekWiaderko Yeap, Workaholic's answer is the way to go. It's very simple and effective solution.You can upvote the comments by hovering on the comment and on the left a up-arrow icon will appear. You can click on that icon